# How do I pass file directory as a method parameter?

Tags: python, file, directory

This codes here is that I read the file configurations first then thereafter I need to pass directory into the method known as the ednotes_extractor.get_ednotes()

```
 from preprocessing import ednotes_extractor

    csf_config_txt = open("..\CFS_Config.txt", "r")

    file_list = []
    root_dir = ""
    edn_txt = ""
    pcr_txt = ""

    for line in csf_config_txt:
        file_list.append(line)

    if "Folder Path = " in file_list[0]:
        root_dir = str(file_list[0])
        root_dir = root_dir.replace("Folder Path = ", "")
        root_dir = root_dir.replace("\n", "")

    if "ED Notes = " in file_list[1]:
        root_dir = str(file_list[1])
        root_dir = root_dir.replace("ED Notes = ", "")
        root_dir = root_dir.replace("\n", "")

    if "Patient Care Record = " in file_list[2]:
        root_dir = str(file_list[2])
        root_dir = root_dir.replace("Patient Care Record = ", "")
        root_dir = root_dir.replace("\n", "")

    print(file_list[2])

    def convert_txt(choices):
        if(choices == 1):
            #I would like to pass a directory in this method called theednotes_extractor 
            ednotes_extractor.get_ednotes(str2=file_list[1])
        elif(choices==2):
            print("Hi")
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help

```
arr1 = [1,2,3]
arr2 = [4,5,6]
```

just add both arrays without []

```
arr3 = arr1 + arr2
```

In your case

```
x = []
for i in range(0, len(arr_cat)):
    x += arr_cat[i]
print(len(x))
```

The above will suffice.

Comment: the problem is that arr_cat consists of 44 arrays and i want to combine these 44 arrays into a single array within itself which is arr_cat @mango

Comment: @Lynn I edited according to your needs. Does above work?

Comment: 3704
2703
5891
3505
4949
2140
2753
1557
2655
3220
2573
2935
1904
8136
2544
3219
12116
2702
3282
2243
2684
3057
3782
4091
3067
2777
1768
2603
4226
4219
2666
2791
4900
4426
3021
3032
2692
1561
2010
4209
3988
2846
3324
2397
2397 @mango my length output is this when i try the above

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension will do it. It will unpack the list of lists and place them into a new list.

```
flat_list = [item for sublist in arr_cat for item in sublist]
arr_cat = flat_list
```

Comment: this does not work @PL200

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from itertools import chain

new_list = list(chain(*arr_cat))
```

Comment: Hi @mehrdad-pedramfar it cannot work...

Comment: @Lynn I think that we misunderstand your desires, can you be a little more specific and share us you desired output?

Comment: I have created another new question on this pls do check @mehrdad-pedramfar

Comment: @Lynn i also checked it, it works just fine for me, can you tell me what do you get from my answer?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/L31307/PycharmProjects/FYP/preprocessing/ednotes_extractor.py", line 154, in <module>
    get_ednotes(str2)
  File "C:/Users/L31307/PycharmProjects/FYP/preprocessing/ednotes_extractor.py", line 120, in get_ednotes
    new_list = list(chain(*new_arr))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable @mehrdad-pedramfar i got this error

Comment: Ow. I think I just understand your problem, you have defined a variable named `list` in your code, don't do this, `list` is a built-in in python, change that variable name to something else like `lst`, then run the code again and update me by your result.@Lynn

Comment: Hi @mehrdad-pedramfar the list is not callable means in ur codes list(chain(*arr_cat)) is not callable...

Comment: @Lynn yes, and it is because you have overridden it in your code.

Comment: okie thanks there are no error right now but there is a small issue here because the result is not what I desired

Comment: what is the result and what is your desires ?